# rrdtool update expected 2 data sources

Tags: rrdtool

I wrote a simple rrdtool database to graph Wi-Fi signal strength and modulation. The signal strength works, but when I try to update the db with MCS information, I get:

```
ERROR: ./somefile.rrd: expected 2 data source readings (got 1) from mcsul15
```

Here's my update code:

```
rssi=`snmpget -v 2c -c communityname 1.2.3.4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.17713.21.1.2.3.0 | awk -v x=4 '{print $x}' | tr -d -`
noisefloor=`snmpget -v 2c -c communityname 1.2.3.4 .1.3.6.1.4.1.17713.21.1.2.20.1.9.1 | awk -v x=4 '{print $x}' | tr -d -`
ulmcs14=`snmpget -v 2c -c communityname 1.2.3.4 CAMBIUM-PMP80211-MIB::ulWLanMCS14Packets.0 | awk -v x=4 '{print $x}'`
ulmcs15=`snmpget -v 2c -c communityname 1.2.3.4 CAMBIUM-PMP80211-MIB::ulWLanMCS15Packets.0 | awk -v x=4 '{print $x}'`
echo $rssi
echo $noisefloor
echo $ulmcs14
echo $ulmcs15
rrdtool update ./somefile.rrd --template \
    rssi:noisefloor N:$rssi:$noisefloor \
    mcsul15:mcsul14 N:$ulmcs15:$ulmcs14
```

Which gives me:

```
68
94
143679
17602658
ERROR: ./somefile.rrd: expected 2 data source readings (got 1) from mcsul15
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `somefile.rrd` has 4 DS defined in it with those 4 names, you should give all four together when updating.  You can only specify one template for the update, and the other parameters should be in that format.

Also, check the names of your DS are correct as your variable is called `$ulmcs15` but the DS is being named `mcsul15`.

```
rrdtool update ./somefile.rrd --template \
  rssi:noisefloor:mcsul15:mcsul14 \
  N:$rssi:$noisefloor:$ulmcs15:$ulmcs14
```

The error message is because in your original commandline, `mcsul15:mcsul14` is being taken as an update vector, not a template.  Thus it is one timestamp and one value, where two were expected.  It would have been a better error message to say something like "timestamp not recognised in 'mcsul15'" but that's a different issue...